# Wordpress print_r issue, not showing value

Tags: php, wordpress

im working with some code in wordpress and a plugin to put php inside of the text box.

but for some reason using this line

```
print_r($csv[0][1]);
```

it doesn't show the value, only comes up blank

update: this is the rest of the code im working with, i placed this is the page.php file

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC88LWXn4SgvVzK3wQAojXk7UM5tDjuWuMZDAjQTGjw/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv';

// $csv = readCSV($csvFile);
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($csv);
// echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: We can not help you without some context, there is nothing wrong with the line provided that `$csv` is an existing 2 dimensional array.

Comment: try with print_r($csv) first

Comment: @stig-js nothing at using

Comment: @Eli ok, i've posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine on mine

```
function _load_google_csv( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'position' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    ob_start();

    // store spreadsheet content into variable
    $data = file_get_contents('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC88LWXn4SgvVzK3wQAojXk7UM5tDjuWuMZDAjQTGjw/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv');

    // Convert Comma separted String to Array
    $data = explode(',', $data );

    // Remove Comment to know the array position of the value you want to pull
    #echo '<pre>', print_r( $data, 1), '</pre>';

    /* The first two array value are like this,  
    [0] => 5X5
[1] => Only 1 Left
5X10

    You see the second array value is "Only 1 Left (Newline) 5X10" and since you don't
     want to pull 5X10, this can be remove from the string using str_replace function, 
     refer to http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp, you may also want
      to improve your CSV format to avoid using of str_replace

    Doing it step by step

    #get the second array value
    $array_1 = $data[1] // Value of $array_1 is "Only 1 Left (Newline) 5X10"

    # Remove "5X10" from $array_1 value using str_replace();
    $desired_value = str_replace('5X10', '', $array_1); 

    echo $desired_value; // $desired_value Will now output a value of "Only 1 Left"

    */

    echo '<pre>', print_r( str_replace('5X10', '', $data[$position]), 1), '</pre>';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('print_csv','_load_google_csv');
```

Shortocode can be use like this, though problem will arise with this method becuase as the str_replace won't work on other array value, you probably need to reformat your CSV to separate each data correctly

```
[print_csv position="0"] // Return the first value of the array
[print_csv position="1"] // Return the second value of the array
```

Comment: what im trying to accomplish is that using print_r will only show the "Only 1 left". $csv[0][1]

Comment: its working perfect, but could you explain this to me      echo '<pre>', print_r( str_replace('5X10', '', $data[1]), 1), '</pre>';     data[1] im going to assume its row 1. whats throwing me off is the 5x10, i change to $data[1]), 2)  it shows 6x10 next to only 1 available

Comment: I edited my answer, you can add shortcode parameter to be able to use it unlimited times with different values refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: you see how you have multiple shortcodes to look for the position, is it possible to jump to a specific row as well vs the column we are looking it for example we have above 5x5 @silver

Answer (score 0):

try `print_r($csv);` first to ensure that $csv is set and is not empty.
then figure out whats wrong!

You can also check it using isset
ex:

```
if(!isset($csv[0][1]))
echo 'I am NULL';
```

Comment: i tried what you said, and the only thing that shows up is "I am NULL

Comment: @Eli sounds like `$csv[0][1]` is empty. When you `print_r($csv);` what shows up?

Comment: @Eli that simply means that your array $csv is empty. check the code where it is assigned the values. Maybe those values are out of scope or something else may have happened. please provide some more code.

Comment: i made updates to the code so you can see what im working with

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv = array_filter($csv);

if (!empty($csv)) {
// Your code goes here
}
```

array_filter() function's default behavior will remove all values from array which are equal to null, 0, '' or false.

Otherwise in your particular case empty() construct will always return true if there is at least one element even with "empty" value.

Comment: i made updates to the code so you can see what im working with

Comment: as I understand you need to read CSV of google drive spread sheet

Answer (score 0):

This code working fine.this gives me an array.

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC88LWXn4SgvVzK3wQAojXk7UM5tDjuWuMZDAjQTGjw/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv';

 $csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
 print_r($csv);
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Output like this :

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5X5
            [1] => Only 1 Left
       )
```

...So on

Comment: install wordpress and you will see what im talking about,

Comment: the code works using phpfiddle or my own local server not using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP in the WordPress back-end editor. Maybe with a plugin you can, but not out of the box.

The easiest solution for this is creating a shortcode. Then you can use something like `[input type="text" name"from"]` in your editor.

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}
```

Second function call first one,

```
    function input_func( $atts ) {
        // Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oC88LWXn4SgvVzK3wQAojXk7UM5tDjuWuMZDAjQTGjw/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv';

 $csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
 print_r($csv);
 echo '</pre>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'input', 'input_func' );
```

Comment: that part i got working adding it to the php page itself, whats not working is the print_r portion of it

Comment: print_r($csv[0][1]);//prints row 1, column 1     that is the only part not working. it pulls data from the csv that is loaded so it goes to row 1 column 1. so in this case it skips showing 5x5 but it will only show "Only 1 Available".

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PHP installation has `allow_url_fopen = on`, if not, activate it or download the file to work as a local file.

**fopen** can't read from an URL if this option is not active, more info: http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php